# Angular 7. Add delay for several input components

Tags: angular

I am trying to apply a debounce time for multiple checkboxes in Angular 7. The idea is to delay the API calls for x seconds in order to have better-performing application (checking/unchecking the checkboxes invokes a call to the API).

Each checkbox corresponds to a filter that is sent to the backend when checked/unchecked and that determines the result returned from the server. I have tried using a custom debounce directive suggested in the article mentioned here, https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-custom-debounce-click-directive-in-angular.

But the problem is that Directive is applied to every checkbox which in turn creates a new Observable/Subject which only associated with an individual checkbox. And my goal is to trigger a SINGLE  request after all group of checkboxes were changed.

What is the best way of doing it?

Comment: Can you please share a reproducible code or event better a stackblitz project?

Answer (score 0):

If suggest you use reactive forms the approach can be something like this:

```
@Component({
  template: 'some.component.html',
})
class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  checkbox1 = new FormControl(false);
  checkbox2 = new FormControl(false);
  ...
  form = new FormGroup({
    checkbox1: this.checkbox1,
    checkbox2: this.checkbox2,
    ...
  });

  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      switchMap(value => this.someService.sendRequestToTheServer(value)),
    ).subscribe(serverResponse => this.handleFilterUpdate(serverResponse));
  }

  private handleFilterUpdate(newResultFromTheServer: Result): void {
    // do something with server data
    // for example update dataSource for MatTable
  }
}
```

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-checkbox formControlName="checkbox1">Checkbox1</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox formControlName="checkbox2">Checkbox2</mat-checkbox>
</form>
```

P.S. Don't forget to unsubscribe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't use a reactive form :(  just lots of checkboxes. Maybe that is my problem.

Comment: You can use the same approach still if you create a Subject and on each checkbox change you will put a value to that subject through subject.next(). To listen to such changes you can use (change)="onCheckboxChange()" on each checkbox. Then apply debounce and have the source of you data to send a proper request to the server.